# Не могу понять работает ли Spring Boot приложение на удаленном сервере ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, ssh, развертывание

Ip адрес (185.249.227.104) - белый.

Установил JDK на сервере (openjdk 17.0.5 2022-10-18), компилировал приложение с Java Amazon Correto 17.0.6.

Загрузил по ssh .jar.
Запустил с помощью команды java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.

Вывелся лог в терминал, что Tomcat started on port: 8080 (http), что Started DemoApplication in 22 seconds.

В application.properties указан только порт (server.port=8080)

На локальной машине на windows проверил через IntelliJ IDEA, все работает, через localhost:8080 контроллер отрабатывает.

Так же добавил System.out.println() до и после метода run() в main(). Ничего в консоли не увидел, но ошибок тоже не получил.

Не понимаю, как проверить работоспособность программы. Как задеплоить её в Ubuntu. Делал по нескольким примерам, результат одинаковый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После запуска java появилась в процессах

[image: После запуска]

Пытаюсь сделать get-запрос через консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь сделать get-запрос через адресную строку с другого ПК: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: направьте, пожалуйста, в какую сторону думать, что гуглить

Comment: А где вы запускаете Ubuntu? В любом случае, если к хосту вы смогли подключиться по ssh(порт 22), но не можете подключиться к порту 8080, то возможно порт 8080 заблокирован для доступа через интернет. Проверьте настройки фаервола.

Comment: Да, проблема была в нём. Разрешил использовать порт 8080 через firewall:
sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp